# P Channel MOSFET gate controlled by N Channel MOSFET (rather than NPN). Crazy?

Tags: microcontroller, npn, powermosfet

I needed a generalized circuit that would switch on/off any device on the Vcc side with varying voltage (3.3 to 24 V) and current (0 to ~10 A).  A P Channel MOSFET is an obvious choice, but I didn't want to use an bipolar junction transistor (BJT) with it to control it's gate because the current would vary by each application and require a different resistor for the BJT .  So I came up with the idea of using an N Channel MOSFET to manage the P Channel MOSFET gate.  I made the circuit shown and it works for a small LED and a 4 A motor connected to 12 V.  Crazy?  What are the downsides to this approach?

[image]

Comment: The basic idea is good. You do need to double check everything over the full voltage range. For example, when Vin is at its highest, what is Vgs of the PMOS when the switch is "on?" Is it higher than Vgs(max) from the PMOS datasheet? What is Vgs of the PMOS when Vin is at its lowest? Is it high enough to insure that the PMOS is fully on? What is the power dissipation in the gate-source resistor when Vin is at its highest? Etc.

Comment: You can use a "jellybean" NMOS such as a BSS138 or BSS123. No need to use a large power MOSFET just to control the gate of the PMOS.

Comment: Conversely, when Vin is at its lowest, how can you make sure that the PMOS is fully turned on? The threshold voltage could be as high as 4.0 V, and that only gets you 250 uA of drain current.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments.  The P Channel MOSFET needs -2.4 V to fully turn it on.  So if I understand it correctly, my circuit would only be able to switch something at Vcc = 5.7 V for 3.3 V logic, and Vcc = 7.4 V for 5.0 logic.  If so, that works for me since I'm really interested in 9, 12, 24 VDC.  I agree the power N Channel MOSFET to control the gate is excessive, and the BSS138 or BSS123 is very helpful (just purchased something similar).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic circuit. I have not carefully analyzed it to make sure it will work across the range you need. But you should be able to make it work by tweaking the resistor values, if needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOHd9I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R3 'ensures', not 'insures'. Sorry to be pedantic!

Comment: @Kartman I will take your word about that insofar as correct usage in Australia goes. But in common usage in the US, "insure" and "ensure" are essentially interchangeable when used in this sense. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insure

Comment: that explains it. Do you have car ensurance companies over there?? In Australia, we just follow our colonial rulers.

Comment: @Kartman Note how I said "when used in this sense."  When referring to something to do with an insurance policy, they are not interchangeable. But when referring to the meaning "make sure" then they are. So, no, we don't have ensurance companies. ;-)